# Total Chromatic Number of Regular Bipartite Graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

What can we say about the total chromatic number of regular bipartite graphs that are not complete? Can we say they are of type 1[Total Colorable(no adjacent/incident elements have same color) by $\Delta+1$ colors where $\Delta$ is the maximum degree of the graph].

Can we say that regular, noncomplete bipartite graphs are formed by removing 1-factors recursively? If that be the case, then I think these graphs are of type 1. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

On the other hand, can we use adjacent strong edge coloring, as mentioned [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11425-008-0153-5.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, any even cycle graph with order not divisible by $3$ is a regular bipartite graph with total chromatic number $4=\Delta+2\,\,,\Delta=2$. Therefore, it may be conjectured that a regular bipartite graph with every cycle(or posibly girth) divisible by $3$ would satisfy being type $1$.